# Silex and SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I followed this (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) tutorial for creating API Key Authenticator. It's almost same as one in this tutorial.

Problem is now how to register this in silex? Is this even possible, if not can you point me to something similar for silex?

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on the same issue right now. [Here](https://gist.github.com/kwisatz/cfe8d8ed89764ea899fb) example, how to integrate SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface to silex.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.